# Same math logic, different results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How am I getting different results from the following two queries? a,b,c are float and I would assume these return the same results but they are slightly off.

```
SELECT (a-b)+(c) 
FROM
    (
            select  sum([Actual Freight Per Line Amt]) a, 
                    sum([fedex charge per line amt]) b, 
                    sum([inbound freight cost]) c 
             from stg.invoices where year([gl date]) = '2016'
    ) foo
```

results in: -5822899.31314175

&

```
SELECT SUM((a-b)+(c))
FROM
    (
            select  [Actual Freight Per Line Amt] a, 
                    [fedex charge per line amt] b, 
                    [inbound freight cost] c 
             from stg.invoices where year([gl date]) = '2016'
    ) foo
```

results in: -5796251.59304654

Comment: Please give examples of how they are off.

Comment: how "slightly" are they off? if they're floats it could easily be rounding error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are any of your values NULL?

Say, you have data such as:

```
a        b        c
NULL     1        2
1        2        3
```

Your first query will provide a result of 3.

Your second query will provide a result of 2.

Comment: This was the case...I had nulls and the bottom query was calculating wrong because of that. I had to add in ISNULL(x,0)

Answer (score 5):

When you are doing arithmetic on a lot of floating point numbers, the ordering matters.  A canonical example is:

```
1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 + -1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 + 38
```

If this is evaluated as:

```
(1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 + -1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000) + 38
```

You'll get 38.  The "38" is so much smaller than the other number that a floating point representation cannot represent the value.

If it is evaluated at:

```
1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 + (-1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 + 38)
```

You'll get 0.

I recommend that you use `decimal`s for the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of floats.
And it is not about big numbers or small numbers.
It is about the accuracy limitation of this numbers' representing method.

```
declare @t table (f float);
insert into @t(f) values (0.1),(0.2),(-0.2),(-0.1);
select sum(f) from @t;
```

> 2.77555756156289E-17

```
declare @t table (f float);
insert into @t(f) values (0.1),(0.2),(-0.3);
select sum(f) from @t;
```

> 5.55111512312578E-17